# AWS Lambda IAM Failing to Connect AWS IoT

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-iot

We have a use case where we need a Lambda function to connect to AWS IoT with the ability to subscribe and publish to a topic. We developed the application using the [AWS IoT SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java). We would like to use MQTT over WebSocket on port 443 so we used this constructor:

```java
// AWS IAM credentials could be retrieved from AWS Cognito, STS, or other secure sources
AWSIotMqttClient client = new AWSIotMqttClient(clientEndpoint, clientId, awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, sessionToken);

// optional parameters can be set before connect()
client.connect();
```

And to grab the credentials we are using:

```java
EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider();
```

Our lambda function has been given external access and has an IAM role granted to it for testing with all permissions:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now what is interesting is that when we test this locally it works great. :). Everything works as expected. However, when we test it in Lambda we are getting the following error:

```
Aug 27, 2019 8:56:53 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.mqtt.AwsIotMqttConnectionListener onFailure

08:56:53 WARNING: Connect request failure

08:56:53 MqttException (0) - java.lang.NullPointerException

08:56:53 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ExceptionHelper.createMqttException(ExceptionHelper.java:38)

08:56:53 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:664)

08:56:53 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

08:56:53 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

08:56:53 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.receiveHandshakeResponse(WebSocketHandshake.java:133)

08:56:53 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketHandshake.execute(WebSocketHandshake.java:74)

08:56:53 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.websocket.WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.start(WebSocketSecureNetworkModule.java:77)

08:56:53 at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.ClientComms$ConnectBG.run(ClientComms.java:650)

08:56:53 ... 1 more

08:56:53 Aug 27, 2019 8:56:53 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection onConnectionFailure

08:56:53 INFO: Connection temporarily lost

08:56:53 Aug 27, 2019 8:56:53 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AwsIotConnection onConnectionFailure

08:56:53 INFO: Connection retry cancelled or exceeded maximum retries

08:56:53 Aug 27, 2019 8:56:53 AM com.amazonaws.services.iot.client.core.AbstractAwsIotClient onConnectionClosed

08:56:53 INFO: Client connection closed: 7f5e5b0d-d41a-48d1-955e-d71f2e1d5e51
```

After digging through various issues and the SDK code the NPE has been changed in a later release for a more useful error message that the connection auth was rejected. Unfortunately due to another bug regarding a recent Paho upgrade that introduced a compatibility bug we cant upgrade just yet until our friends at Paho take care of fixing the [upgrade header issues](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.java/issues/234) and our friends at AWS make Paho 1.2.0 compatible with the SDK.

Before anybody advices us that Lambda is **not** suitable for subscribing to long lived MQTT... While we would agree that in many instances it is not suitable in our specific use case it's perfect. We are simply trying to understand why it works locally but not in Lambda.

---

**UPDATE:**

OK I added the ability for the app to look at a custom set of ENV vars first and then if they are **not** present then fall back to using the default ENV vars provided by the lambda function for credentials. I then added a user to the **same role** that is assigned to the lambda function and used those credentials directly in the ENV to override those passed by lambda.... and it works!!! remove those and let lambda pass give me the credentials and I get the error again.

:(

Comment: You can increase Timeout of your lambda. Also please check role and permission of your AWS lambda.

Comment: @DimoMohit Timeout on the Lambda is set to 300 secs. This error appears after around 2-10 secs. I have checked the role and permissions and they are 100% as stated above.

Comment: without going too deep into your problem usually something works locally since you are calling it with your own (probably admin) credentials. My tipp would be adjusting the policies in the role which you attached to your lambda function.

Comment: @benra I completely agree that this look like a credential problem. The mystery is that I have attached an admin execution role to lambda.

Comment: I think within your AWS IoT you also need to define policies to allow your lambda function to connect/subscribe/ etc.

Comment: @benra To my knowledge that is only if you are using MQTT over TLS 1.2 on port 8883. This then requires a cert with an assigned policy. I don't think that applies with IAM access over WebSocket.